# Question format but not a question

Tags: wh-questions

Is the following sentence correct?

> New Zealand takes the same position on many of those issues, so, is Jacinda worried it'll hurt our relationship with the superpower.

That's what I am hearing on 1:55 in [this video](https://youtu.be/RtSKPSSd_sg?t=111).

If correct, what is this called in grammar?

Comment: That's a question.  So, is Jacinda worried it'll hurt our relationship with the superpower?

Comment: What exactly is this question about? Is it about whether it's correct to join a statement and a question with the conjunction "so"? Or something else? Please [edit] to clarify what kind of answer you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually two sentences. One is a statement, and the other is a question.

> New Zealand takes the same position on many of those issues.
> So, is Jacinda worried it'll hurt our relationship with the superpower?

You may see such pairs of sentences joined together with a comma (forming a "comma splice") but that isn't good punctuation.

The question part may be a *rhetorical question*, that is the narrator isn't expecting anybody to give an answer, but is using a question to get the audience thinking about this issue.

Comment: We commonly join two clauses with "so". Why would it be ungrammatical in this case? Is it because the first clause is a statement and the second is a question?

Comment: You might use "so" to introduce a clause that follows logically or when the first clause gives the reason for the second.  "It's sunny, so I'm wearing a t-shirt."    But in the OP's question, "so" isn't like that.  It's a linking word to flow the two sentences together.  It is almost just filler. It doesn't actually have much meaning. A question can't follow (logically or by reason) from a statement. You should not punctuate these with a comma.